# Could not find file on the Ansible Controller - Terraform - Ansible

Tags: ansible, terraform

I have a `terraform` code

**Terraform code:**

```
resource "null_resource" callfileen {
    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command =  "ansible-playbook -i /home/user/${var.name}-inventory.ini  /home/user/ansible_files/call_file.yml -vvvv"
    
  }
```

which calls a `ansible yml` file, which has a block like below

```
vars_files:
  - /home/user/ansible_vars_files/ansible_vars_file.yml
```

For some reason the below error keeps coming up

```
ERROR! vars file /home/user/ansible_vars_files/ansible_vars_file.yml was not found
Could not find file on the Ansible Controller.
If you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option
```

That file is very much there, if i run `ansible-playbook` without terraform it seems to pick that file. I am not sure what am i missing here. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: and what is the result of `command = "ls -l /home/user/ansible_vars_files/ansible_vars_file.yml; id -a; ansible-playbook ...and-the-rest..."`?

Comment: sorry? i dont get the command